# Photo input with Expo

Tags: reactjs, input, expo, photo

I am trying to create an app that will allow you to choose an image from your device and load it into the app. To do this i am using expo. Im getting this errors and do not know what to do now.
Any type of help is very much appreciated.

These are the dependencies i have installed: react-scripts, react-dom, react-native-web, react-art, react-router-native, react-router-dom, expo, expo-image-picker, expo-permissions, react-native.

ERRORS

node scripts/start.js

(node:7488) [DEP_WEBPACK_SINGLE_ENTRY_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: SingleEntryPlugin was renamed to EntryPlugin
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Invalid options object. Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API
schema.

- options should be one of these:
  object { resourceRegExp, contextRegExp? } | object { checkResource }
  Details:

  - options misses the property 'resourceRegExp'. Should be:
    RegExp
    -> A RegExp to test the request against.
  - options misses the property 'checkResource'. Should be:
    function
    -> A filter function for resource and context.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! photo-input@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the photo-input@0.1.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gituk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-05T13_17_39_903Z-debug.log

And this is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'

export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);


  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing:true
    })

    if(!result.cancelled){
      setImage(result.uri)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Click here to pick an image" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri:image }} style={{ width:200, height:200}}/>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am following a tutorial so it should be working but it is not. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the Deprecation warning, it looks like it could stem from a new version of webpack. I would suggest installing the latest version in your package.json file, currently it's 5.56.1. If that doesn't work, [version "5.52.1"](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/33216#issuecomment-921013343) might be a solution.

```
... 
"dependencies":{
    "webpack": "5.56.1"
  },
...
```

After looking through the documentation on [Expo's Website](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/), it looks like they provide a good usage example that catches permissions issues and installation steps. Have you tried something like this:

```
expo install expo-image-picker
```

> ^ Make sure you have run the expo install command as well.
> (I've changed the function name below to match your use case)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```